# Erro javascript: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function

Tags: javascript, android, ionic

Ao testar meu aplicativo em um android 4.4, aparece este erro, porem no android 5 o erro não aparece.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser.

Comment: Confira esta resposta no SO em inglês: [Está em javaScript mas a logica é a mesma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573061/uncaught-syntaxerror-in-strict-mode-code-functions-can-only-be-declared-at-top?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a sugestão do Vitor no comentário a minha pergunta, consegui identificar e resolver o problema, decidi escrever esta resposta para ajudar alguém que possa ter o mesmo problema.

**O Problema**

Em alguns algoritmos eu criava uma função dentro de uma condição ou laço, isso até o es5 gera erro, no es6 o erro não ocorre. A partir do Android 5, o webview passa a implementar es6, por isso o erro não ocorre mais.

*Exemplo:*

```
function getNome(){
   if (nome !== null){

      return nome();

      function nome(){
         return _nome;
      } 
   }
}
```

**Solução**

Para que o problema não ocorra, devemos retirar a declaração de *function nome ()* de dentro do *if*.

```
function getNome(){
   if (nome !== null){
      return nome();
   }

   function nome(){
      return _nome;
   }
}
```

Assim funciona perfeitamente.